# IntelliJ IDEA expand/collapse tags in *.iws, *.ipr and *.iml files

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to get IDEA to recognize its own workspace, project and module files as XML files so that I can expand/collapse tags. However, when I try to modify the XML file type to add any of those extensions, IDEA complains that those are reserved. Now, if it knows about those extensions, why doesn't it let me expand/collapse tags? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support for tag expand/collapse is just not there, because these files are not supposed to be edited (or frequently viewed) by people, it's just some internal information. If you have a specific use case when it's really needed, please describe it in a new issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard

Comment: Will do. I'm using IntelliJ 12 and I am generating those files using the Gradle IDEA plugin. I know version 13 has out-of-the-box support for Gradle but it doesn't work with Scala module. It's convenient to look at the files to easily write scripts to customize stuff like run configurations and the likes.

Comment: So I'd suggest you also file a feature request for IDEA+Gradle to support Scala.

Comment: BTW as a workaround you can just copy the text to a plain XML file and get all the folding and highlighting there.